# is it possible to get the count and types of class-members of a unknown class?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, c++17

i have a black-box class like:

```
class foo
{/* body is unavailable for me to inspect */};
```

`foo` can be a template.

This class is the ultimate black-box;

- I don't know anything about its members,

- I don't know anything about its methods,

- etc.

I am trying to implement a `class_traits` class:

```
template <typename T>
class class_traits
{
// impl
}
```

which will let me do the following (or at least something that will have a similar result)

```
int main()
{
    cout << class_traits<foo>::member_count << endl;
    cout << typeid(class_traits<foo>::member<0>::type).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(class_traits<foo>::member<1>::type).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(class_traits<foo>::member<2>::type).name() << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Is it possible to do sth like that? If so, how?

I am limited to `c++17`.

I am completly fine with macros and other "hacky" solutions (if possible I'd like to keep this to compile-time rather then to run-time).

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: you must at least have a declaration, no? Otherwise what else can you do with `foo`?

Comment: What you are asking for is called "reflection", and it is not available in C++ (though there have been some proposals to add it).

Comment: @NeilButterworth this is not an XY problem. I literally need a generic way to list members of any class.

Comment: "I literally need a generic way to list members of any class." - that's an XY pproblem - WHY do you think you need to do that?

Comment: @aschepler here is a nice talk about the reflection ts https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMuML6vLSus

Comment: what you can do is: check if a class has a member of a given name, though I doubt you want to test against all possible names...

Comment: IMO, needing this is usually wrong.

Comment: are you okay with restricting yourself to AggregateTypes (perhaps non-recursively)? If yes, there's a not-too-difficult solution in C++17 which can be backported to C++11.
Note that most classes can be decomposed to: base AggregateType(s) that you inherit from (perhaps via `private`/`protected` inheritance) and an interface/ctor level of methods. If you are granted access to the decomposed base class(es) as above, you can do e.g. some limited serialization this way.

Answer (score 5):

"is it possible to get the count and types of class-members of a unknown class?" - No.

What you are looking for is a feature called *reflection*, which C++ (17 and earlier) does *not* have (future versions *may* have some form of it).

Comment: not yet, but hopefully soon, see here: https://github.com/cplusplus/reflection-ts

Answer (score 3):

If your class is something that can be destructured, you can abuse *structured bindings* to get a primitive form of reflection. See [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) for an example.

From the [README](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get/blob/develop/README.md):

```
struct some_person {
    std::string name;
    unsigned birth_year;
};

int main() {
    some_person val{"Edgar Allan Poe", 1809};

    std::cout << boost::pfr::get<0>(val)                // No macro!
        << " was born in " << boost::pfr::get<1>(val);  // Works with any aggregate initializables!
}
```

Comment: Magic get is super cool as a demonstration technique, but unfortunately, very limited when it comes to real life usage. Biggest limitation is, indeed, inability to get field names.